# Activate script on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, feedburner

If I want to activate a piece of code on click I would put the code in the head like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFeed() {

...code... 

}
    </script>
```

And then call it like this:

```
<button onclick="myFeed();"> click </button>
```

But now Im facing a problem using FeedBurner. All I have is this:

```
<script src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/nu/gbKB?format=sigpro" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

How can I assign a function to it like I did in the first example and call it in the body??

Comment: Updated my answer to provide you with complete solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Liam's answer, just some details:

```
function myFeed()
{
  document.write('<script src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/nu/gbKB?format=sigpro" type="text/javascript" ></script>');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wh5cW/1/)

Comment: Yes, i agree with you but if you use the answer i provide it goes it to the head, which is better practice, my solution now has example

Answer (score 1):

On click just add the javascript to the DOM,

Heres how to do it

I would also add an ID to the script you add it to make it easier if you have to remove it.

This method i've provided adds it to the head of the DOM.

```
function addJavascript(jsname,pos) {
var th = document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0];
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
s.setAttribute('src',jsname);
th.appendChild(s);
}
```

- Line 1 Opens the function with parameters of script location and
  where to add it e.g myscript.js , head
- Line 2 Cets the element you told it in the pos varible
- Line 3 Creates script tags
- Line 4 Adds script type
- Line 5 Adds source
- Line 6 Adds the script,tag,type to the DOM

[Link to resource (JS Dom Manipulation)](http://javascript.about.com/library/bladdjs.htm)